# Python: working with bits. Coding nucleotides with zeros and ones

Tags: python, bit, bioinformatics

I'd want to encode nucleotides 'A', 'G', 'C' and 'T' using bit encoding in Python. For example:

```
'A' = 00
'G' = 01
'C' = 10
'T' = 11
```

In order to build a huge dict containing k-mers like:

```
dic = { 'ATGACTGACT':231, 'AAATGACGGAC':500 ... }
```

I think this could reduce the amount of memory needed by that dict since 'ATGC' would need 4 bytes but the same word would need 8 bits with a bit encoding.

I'm not sure if this can be done and, if so, how could I do it using Python

Thanks in Advance!

EDITED: I'm sorry I didn't explain myself right.

What I want is to walk through a sequence composed by 'ATGC's with a sliding window of size k, and count how many times each k-mer appears in that seq. For example:

```
'ATGAATGAA' # with a sliding window of 5 would be
 dic = { 'ATGAA':2, 'TGAAT':1, 'GAATG':1, 'AATGA':1, }
```

Since I'd want to construct the dict with all possible combinations of 'AGTC' of size k before start to reading the sequence, in order to access that dict with each k-mer as key and sum 1 to its value, I was wondering if it would be possible k-mers on that dict to be stored with bit encoding. More or less:

```
dic = {1011001010: 3, 0000110011: 666, ...  etc }
```

Currently I'm building that dict with itertools.

```
# k-mers of size 8
{''.join(x):0 for x in itertools.product('ATGC', repeat=8)}
```

I guess another problem will be that each k-mer will need to be converted to that bit encoding in order to access the dict

Comment: It's not clear: you still have full and bit version of k-mer in your dic example, so where is the memory reduction? Another important question - is what are you going to do after that with this bits? partial search? using metrics?

Comment: What would `00001100` encode? AAT? TA? AATA?

Comment: For variable-length strings you could use a module like [bitstring](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/index.html) (specifically the ConstBitStream for use as a dict key). I don't know how this would actually affect performance / memory use. By the way, could you be [prematurely optimizing](http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451)? I'm not saying you are; the question is, would a constant 4x memory improvement be worth the additional complexity, and should that change be made now?

Comment: To amplify @Lack, unless you have demonstrated that there is a memory deficiency, don't optimize for expected problems. Furthermore, you should explore [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) and not reinvent the wheel. Part of the justification for using Python is the wealth of third party libraries that may already do what you want.

Comment: I don't think I am prematurely optimizing. Actually, I already have my program working, and I used Biopython. The problem is that it takes 7 hours processing the Human Genome and now I'm trying with another approach.

Comment: It sounds like you're just trying to do kmer counting. There's been a huge amount of work done to optimise solutions to that problem. Check out Jellyfish, KMC, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your kmers to binary, but as Ignacio points out you still need to know their length, so you may need to store that as well.  So, for very long sequences this will still save memory space.

Here is some example code which takes sequences, encodes them and decodes them back again:

```
encoding_map = {'A': 0, 'G': 1, 'C': 2, 'T': 3}
decoding_lst = ['A', 'G', 'C', 'T']


def encode(k):
    code = 0
    for ch in k:
        code *= 4
        code += encoding_map[ch]
    return code, len(k)


def decode(enc):
    code, length = enc
    ret = ''
    for _ in range(length):
        index = code & 3
        code >>= 2
        ret = decoding_lst[index] + ret
    return ret


kmers = ['ATGACTGACT', 'ATGC', 'AATGC']

kmerdict = {k: encode(k) for k in kmers}

print(kmerdict)

for key, enc in kmerdict.items():
    print(enc, decode(enc))
```

typical output:

```
{'AATGC': (54, 5), 'ATGC': (54, 4), 'ATGACTGACT': (215883, 10)}
(54, 5) AATGC
(54, 4) ATGC
(215883, 10) ATGACTGACT
```

By the way, it shouldn't matter how long the sequence is, Python should be able to handle the encoding and decoding because integers expand to enough bits to hold the number.

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you asked for

```
In [11]: d={'A':'00','G':'01','C':'10','T':'11'}

In [12]: int('0B'+''.join([d[c] for c in 'ATGACTGACT']),2)
Out[12]: 215883

In [13]: int('0B'+''.join([d[c] for c in 'ATGACTGACT'[::-1]]),2)
Out[13]: 925212

In [14]:
```

but the objections given in their comments by *pmod* and *Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams* are really important ones, I think that you should seriously reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 1):

As @gbofi's answer suggests, it is pretty simple to convert a k-mer to an integer between `0` and `4**k - 1`. An alternative, primarily mathematical way of doing the encoding would be:

```
def kmer_to_int(kmer):
    return sum(4**i * "ATGC".index(x) for i, x in enumerate(kmer))
```

I've not tested if this is faster than building a binary string and then converting it to an int.

This code gives the first character in the input the lowest bit position, so `"AT"` becomes `0b0100`, or `4` and `"TA"` becomes `0b0001` or `1`. If you want the encoding to treat the first letters as most most significant, use `enumerate(reversed(kmer))` instead of `enumerate(kmer)` in the generator expression.

As others have commented, these integers are only unique for a given length `k`. The same integer will be given as the encoding for strings of differing lengths if they only differ by the number of trailing `A`s (e.g. `"ATG"`, `"ATGA"`, `"ATGAA"`, `"ATGAAA"`, etc. all encode to `36`).

As for your wider goal of counting the occurrences of specific k-mers in a larger sequence, I'm not sure if you'll see an advantage of encoding the k-mers in this way or not. The benefits may depend on the details of your dataset.

An advantage of integer keys is that they'd allow you to use a list, rather than a dictionary to hold your counts. You can build an appropriate list with `lst = [0] * 4**k`, then increment a value you've seen with `lst[kmer_to_int(kmer)] += 1`. Lists do have lower overheads than dictionaries, given the same number of entries, but I'm not sure if the difference will be large enough to be helpful.

If your data is sparsely distributed (that is, many of the 4**k possible k-mer sequences never appear in your input), using a list may still waste a lot of memory, since the list is always `4**k` elements long. A better approach might be to use some other methods to streamline your `dict` code for sparse data.

One option is to some of the `dict` class's methods to avoid the need to initialize all the values in your result set to `0`. If you change your increment code to do `d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + 1`, it will work whether or not the `key` was already in the dictionary.

Another option would be to use `collections.Counter` rather than a regular `dict`. The `Counter` class is specifically designed for counting instances of items in an input sequence, which seems to be exactly what you're doing. It considers any key it hasn't seen already to have a value of `0`.